# How to add Dynamically sorting data in NSDictionary in Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting, nsdictionary

I want to create a address book, I use below link for my reference.
[Address Book](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/)

In the demo they have added static data, Now how to do the same thing dynamically?
Here is my Implementation and the screenshot :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
                @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
                @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
                @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
                @"G" : @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"],
                @"H" : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"],
                @"K" : @[@"Koala"],
                @"L" : @[@"Lion", @"Llama"],
                @"M" : @[@"Manatus", @"Meerkat"],
                @"P" : @[@"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear"],
                @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"],
                @"S" : @[@"Seagull"],
                @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
                @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};

    animalSectionTitles = [[animals allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    animalIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [animalSectionTitles count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [animalSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [animalSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [animals objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionAnimals count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *sectionTitle = [animalSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [animals objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *animal = [sectionAnimals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = animal;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile"];

    return cell;
}
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return animalIndexTitles;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [animalSectionTitles indexOfObject:title];
}
```

[image: Requirement]

Below is my response which I need to use to show the users.

> {
>       detail =     (
>                   {
>               displayname = Mihir;
>               email = “mihir@gmail.com";
>               uuid = "user1”;
>           },
>            {
>               displayname = Aakash;
>               email = “aakash@gmail.com";
>               uuid = "user2”;
>       },
>       {
>               displayname = hardik;
>               email = “hardik@gmail.com";
>               uuid = "user2”;
>   }
>       );
>       httpCode = 200;
>       message = Success;
>   }

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to sort the API response data and display accordingly to alphabetically?

Comment: You probably want to sort and sectioned `displayname `, iOS have support for them, you can use [UILocalized​Indexed​Collation](https://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/) for that

Comment: @HardikS my api response is already sorted. I just need to put it on the list view. I have given my sample response in question, Please ignore the order of response.

Comment: @Tj3n I know that,  but how to use `uilocalizedindexedcollation`  in my scenario?